# Overwriting the CSS parameters value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the input text box to red on some error. The code which i am given has a css style sheet and it just changes the color of all the textboxes to red if I want to use that style sheet. Is there a way round to sent the textbox border color to red. (Here I am not concerned how I will look for the error just want to know the type of attributes required to set the color of any individual textbox to red)

**Here is the code for the text input**

```
 <input name="count" 
 type="number" 
 walked="true" 
 autocomplete="off" 
 class="htmlplusinput numberinput novalue" 
 style="width: 24px; " 
 id="htmlplusinputnumberinput19" 
 hasobj="true" 
 novaluedisplay="number">
```

Here I also want to avoid using id to access this text box since the id's are dynamically changed. (I mean to say that the id htmlplusinputnumberinput19 will be other time htmlplusinputnumberinput789)
so thats why a better solution will be if I can used some other parameter.

Here is the **CSS style** sheet which is applied to all the input textboxes on the page

```
 input[type="text"], .htmlplusinput {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  }
```

Comment: You might getter better response if you clarify your question: what is the stylesheet? What are the other non-standard (e.g. walked) for? Is there any way to know if a input is in error by just lookin at the attributes etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the response...I am not concerned about looking at the error..I just want to change the color of the textinput border...I have added the CSS code above..

Comment: Then you should just change the "gray" into red, or in javascript: document.getElementsByTagName.each(function(input){input.style.borderColor = 'red'}); (ECMAScript5 but easy to do in older javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give you advice on how to select the input element other than by its id, you need to provide more information about the markup of the page. It may work with something like this:

```
$('#example-form input[name=count]')
```

If you use jQuery, setting css attribute values is easy:

```
$('input[name=count]').css('border-color', 'red');
```

Also you may add an error class to the element:

```
$('input[name=count]').addClass('error');
```

Comment: Thanks...Please can you give the answer in javascript...the code is also in javascript and I don't know jquery :(

Comment: Judy, jQuery is a JavaScript library that makes DOM manipulation easier. This is all JavaScript.

Comment: Judy, is it possible that you include the jQuery library to the page? You will have a lot of benefits. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks guys...No..I cant add libraries to the page :(

Comment: No, it doesn't: `It's important to note that this method does not replace a class.` see here: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 5):

@Judy the best way I guess is your validation code point out the ID of troubled element. so, you can use some jQuery like that `$('#myElementId').css('border-color', 'red');`

Comment: Thanks... I will really appreciate if you can give answer with javascripts..sorry for trouble..(from above code looks like(from my poor understanding of jquery) I need to access the element with id..but id are dynamically changing ..

Comment: @Judy you can clarify you question telling us how you "know" that some particular input is "invalid" or "in error". based on your validation code, we can try provide some better solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would add a class to erroneous input.

CSS:

```
input.error { color: red; };
```

Javascript (on validation point) :

```
currentValidatingInput.className += " error";
```